# Radius of largest sector that can fit in a rectangle, given the 'start angle' and 'sweep angle' of the sector

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

**What we know:**

I have a rectangle with a given Width and Height:
[image]

Inside that rectangle, I want to fit an ellipse sector, with a known "Start angle" and "Sweep angle."  Some contrived, random examples:
[image]

**The question:**

Given the Width and Height of the rectangle, and given the 'start angle' and 'sweep angle' of the sector, how do I determine the largest RadiusX and RadiusY values of the resulting sector which will completely fit inside the rectangle?
[image]

How do I solve for Radius X and Radius Y?

**BONUS**: How do I calculate the X/Y coordinates for the origin of the ellipse, as it fits inside the rectangle?

Comment: Your "start angle" and "sweep angle" are they the real angles formed by the sides of the sector, or they are rather referred to a circle?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  The five examples above are just 5 random examples, which show an ellipse sector with the given 'begin' angle and 'sweep' angle length.

Comment: In the picture below, your sweep angle for the ellipse on the right is 129° or 100°? [Picture] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/fdrRM.png)

Comment: I think I see.  By "sweep angle" I refer to the degree of rotation, clockwise, starting from the start angle.